# PyCUDA - ElementWise fails for equality checking

Tags: python, gpu, pycuda

I'm trying to build an equality checker for two arrays that can I can run on my GPU using PyCUDA.

Following the example given on the PyCUDA [GPU Arrays documentation page](https://documen.tician.de/pycuda/array.html#module-pycuda.elementwise), I attempted to write my own implementation. But whilst the below code works as expected for arithmetic, e.g. `"z[i] = x[i] + y[i]"`, it returns erroneous output for the equality checker operand `"z[i] = x[i] == y[i]"`.

```py
import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
import numpy as np
from pycuda.elementwise import ElementwiseKernel

matrix_size = (5,)
a = np.random.randint(2, size=matrix_size)
b = np.random.randint(2, size=matrix_size)

print a
print b

a_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(a) 
b_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(b)

eq_checker = ElementwiseKernel(
        "int *x, int *y, int *z",
        "z[i] = x[i] == y[i]",
        "equality_checker")

c_gpu = gpuarray.empty_like(a_gpu)
eq_checker(a_gpu, b_gpu, c_gpu)

print c_gpu
```

Which prints out something like:

```
[0 1 0 0 0]
[0 1 1 1 0]
[4294967297 4294967297          0          1          1]
```

Does anyone understand why this error is occurring, or at least have an alternative PyCUDA method to achieve the desired function?

Comment: Could you try adding parentheses `z[i] = (x[i] == y[i])` and see if that works? If not, if you're only using 0/1 values, consider using the `&` operator instead, as it'd accomplish the same thing in that case, and it'd likely be faster too.

Comment: Unfortunately the parentheses do not fix it. The `&` operator works fine for binary, but ultimately I would like to use it for non-binary integers. I am not very familiar with C code, but is there anything about the equality operator that makes it fundamentally differ from arithmetic and boolean ones?

Comment: It might be worth type casting the result, just to make sure you get what you're expecting: `z[i] = (int)(x[i] == y[i])`. I don't do much C these days either, so I'm kinda guessing here since I'm not positive what the `==` operator return type is

Comment: Again, sadly, it gives the same bug. :(. I've raised it as an issue on the PyCUDA GitHub and will update with any answer I get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! The problem was that numpy automatically returns 64-bit integers, whereas PyCUDA only standardly accepts 32-bit integers.

This is therefore fixed by specifying the type of ints numpy generates, such as:

```
a = np.random.randint(2, size=matrix_size, dtype=np.int32)
b = np.random.randint(2, size=matrix_size, dtype=np.int32)
```

after which it works as expected.